# Sharepoint 2013 Powershell: checked out files move ownership or download

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, file, check-out, download

I have a large set of files that have not been checked in.

Is it possible to move the checked out status to another user (not take control myself)?

Or plan b, download the checked out files through a script?

I can get a handle on the checked out items, but I cant see any move ownership method, and when I try to download them the $item.OpenBinary throws a "Exception calling "OpenBinary" with 0 arguments" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kristaps,

I've managed to work around the issue another way
For all checked out files, take ownership, check in, change permissions, while impersonating another user get a handle on the web again, then check out as that user.

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could execute PowerShell script as another user - for example, IIS user (commonly known as "App Pool" user). This would execute your code with a level of permissions of that user - all checked out files will be done by this user. This user will be shown as "System account" without any specific information.

If You cannot execute the whole script under that user, then move "elevated code" in other .ps1 file and call out PowerShell under the context of another user ([link how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989750/running-powershell-as-another-user-and-launching-a-script/38102336)).